# Java encapsulated Array mutator method

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, encapsulation

I have this assignment that i'm trying to code , but unfortunately , It's giving me a hard time.

I've scoured the internet and my textbooks but cannot seem to find an example of this particular predicament.

Basically , i'm required to write a booking engine for a train ,we were given startup code which we are meant to use , and basically write out our methods and plug them into the appropriate classes .

The main problem is that we are required to encapsulate the main array that holds the trainticket objects in a separate class and basically write mutator and accessor methods any interaction with the array is needed , to keep the array inaccessible and secure for times when access isn't needed .

This is the driver class for the program

```
Private static void menuAdd() 


{
       String  passName,op1,op2;
       int seatNum;
       Boolean FCOption,waiter,indicator;
       int duration;
       char fClass,wService;

   System.out.print("Please Enter a seat number :");
   seatNum = stdin.nextInt();
   stdin.nextLine();

   System.out.print("Please Enter the passenger name :");
   passName = stdin.nextLine();
   System.out.print(passName);

   System.out.print("Please Enter number of legs for this trip :");
   duration = stdin.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Would you like to consider a First Class ticket for an additional $20 per leg? :");
   System.out.print("Please enter Y/N");
   op1 = stdin.next();
   fClass =op1.charAt(0);

   stdin.nextLine();
   System.out.print("Would you like to consider a waiter service for a flat $15 Fee?");
   System.out.print("Please enter Y/N");
   op2 = stdin.next();
   wService =op2.charAt(0);


   //Now we create the ticket object

   TrainTicket ticketx = new TrainTicket(seatNum,passName,duration);

   System.out.println("This is an object test printing pax name"+ticketx.getName());

   TicketArray.add(ticketx);
```

}

So basically , i ahve no problem writing the code requesting the various details form the user and then instatiating the object using the constructor call for the TrainTicket Object ,
when i pass along the object to the array class using

```
TicketArray.add(ticketx);
```

eclipse tells me  "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method add(TrainTicket) from the type TicketArray"

This is what the array class looks like

```
    Public class TicketArray
{
   // ..............................................
   // .. instance variables and constants go here ..
   // ..............................................
    int counter ;
    int arraySize =100 ;

   // constructor
   public TicketArray()
   {
      // ....................
      // .. implement this ..
      // ....................
       TrainTicket [] tickets =new TrainTicket[arraySize];
   }

   // add() method:
   // take the passed in TrainTicket object and attempt to store it in the
   // data structure. If the structure is full, or the seat of the given
   // TrainTicket has already been booked, the operation should return
   // false; otherwise return true.

   public boolean add(TrainTicket data)
   {
      // ....................
      // .. implement this ..
      // ....................

       tickets[counter]=data;
      // dummy return value so the skeleton compiles
      return false;
   }
```

Any ideas why it isn't working ?
I'd appreciate if someone can explain  how to encapsulate an array in this manner , i'm familiar with the way constructors work and their methods are written , but for some reason i'm finding it hard to do the same thing with an array.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You need an instance in order to call an instance method. This issue has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: Hi Dave , can you clarify a bit ? an Instance of what ?

Comment: TicketArray, the class you're trying to call an instance method on. Alternatively, you could make it a static method, but ew, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't with mutator or accessor methods or even arrays, but the fact that you don't create an instance of the `TicketArray` class before trying to use it. `add(Ticket t)` is defined as an instance method meaning that you need to have an instance of `TicketArray` before you can add to it.

try this:

```
//create a new Ticket
TrainTicket ticketx = new TrainTicket(seatNum,passName,duration);

//create a new Ticket Array
TicketArray tarr = new TicketArray();
tarr.add(ticketx);
```

Comment: ok , so once I instantiate TicketArray , and pass the ticket object using tarr.add(ticketx); , how do i add the object to the array in the public boolean add(TrainTicket data) method ?

Comment: @user1405824 Well it would be similar to what you have. You need to keep track of the current index into the array, then when you add an element to the array increment the index by 1.